# How to align banner right in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Web shop contains search box and banner after it.
In Internet Explorer 8 banner hides button right part of search box:

In modern browsers banner appears after search box as expected.
How to force site to work in IE8 also ?
I looked into http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/

but dont understand which fix to apply.

jquery, jquery-ui, responsible slides are used.

html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"
        type="text/css" title="ui-theme" />
  <link href="/Content/Css/jquery.ui.menubar.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
  <link href="/Content/Css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header" style="margin: 0; width: 100%">
      <div class="site-topbar">
        <div class='site-topbanner'>
            <div>
              <a class="color-red" href="/Account/LogOn">Sisene</a>
            </div>
<form action="/Store/Browse" class="searchform" method="get" style="margin:0"><input class="searchfield" id="Search" name="Search" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value = &#39;Otsi...&#39;;}" onfocus="if (this.value == &#39;Otsi...&#39;) {this.value = &#39;&#39;;}" type="text" value="Otsi..." /><input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Otsi... " />
</form> 
        </div>
        <ul class="rslides">
<img src="Store/Banner?product=prod1" height='210px'  width='500px' />
     </ul>
      </div>
```

css:

```
.rslides {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

    .rslides li {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

        .rslides li:first-child {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block; 
            float: left;
        }

    .rslides img {
        display: inline-block; 
        float: left;
        border: 0;
    }

    .rslides p {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try this:

```
.site-topbanner {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 80px; /* to counteract losing vertical alignment due to the float */
}
```

The margin was added because the element is now floating and will not respect vertical alignment.